# React JS component not applying CSS margin

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

With react I have created a very simple card component in a `Card.jsx` file. The component looks like this.

```
class Card extends React.Component{

  render() {
    return (
      <div className={style.mainContainer}>
        <div className={style.container}>
          <div className={style.title}>Hello world</div>
          <div className={style.value}></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
}

export default Card
```

In one of my web app's page I have added two cards, and I space them out with flex display.

The page render:

```
function Home() {
    return (
        <div className={style.container}>
            <Card> </Card>
            <Card> </Card>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Container CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;

}
```

The only problem with this code is that the margin-top in the css is not applying margin to the div. I encountered this problem several times, leading me to not be able to use nor padding nor margin. Can someone help? Thanks.

Image of components not being affected by margin
[image]

I found out that trying to reset React's default padding through the following lines of code:

```
* {    
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

was yielding the issue. Nonetheless, how can I reset React's default padding / margin without the styling affecting ALL padding and margins in the app?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure? This seems like a question that should be looking at the rendered markup. You may have a common margin collapse scenario.

Comment: remove !important from the reset, or worse, use it too on your new rules :(

Comment: Your update doesn't really change anything. Unless we can see the rendered HTML and the applied styles I'm not sure how we'd help.

Comment: And React doesn't have default styles. Are you using a layout or style library?

Comment: @isherwood React apps all have a slight margin, that line of code I added tried removing the margin, and it works. Only problem, it removes all margins from the app.

Comment: @isherwood I added the rendered HTML to the question.

Comment: React doesn't do anything to CSS, if there's extra margin it's either the browser's default or some library that you've included. You need to target the elements that have the margin directly instead of zeroing out everything, e.g. if the body has extra margin then `body { margin: 0; }` instead and so on.

Comment: No, you added an image.

Comment: How does the css for container and maincontainer and card look like?

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a bad idea to override the style properties for a lot of elements (the * selector). But, it is ok to override the user agent stylesheet for specific tags. For instance, Chrome automatically adds a margin to the `<body>` tag, so you can override the margin property without using `!important` in React *I think*.

After you remove the `!important` overrides, create a separate container class for your Card component. Setting widths and heights of individual flex items can interfere with the flex container layout, and possibly cause margins to collapse.

Answer (score -1):

Add a padding to container

```
.container {
    padding: 10px;
}
```